# What two TNG episodes does Ashley Judd appear in and does she say she didn't?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I've read that she denies ever being in TNG, though, I believe, she was in two episodes (though I can't remember which ones).

Comment: Is there a definitive list anywhere of 'Lefler's laws'?

Comment: This type of question is a death trap: leaving it open allows for people to ask this about *every single TNG guest star*, or heck *every single guest star on every single SF show ever*. Do we really want the site to be consumed with these types of questions?

Comment: It's not that hard to understand, esp. if you're familiar with Star Trek. But I don't think there's anything wrong with the question. Ashley Judd has tried to deny ever being in Star Trek. Why? And, it's a finite list and a pretty unusual even for such an acto to have been in a cult-classic TV series and go on to be a major star, right? Anyway, the community voted to reopen this one, so.

Comment: People, this is general reference: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ashley_Judd

Comment: @bitmask Memory Alpha, while a very good resource, isn't considered to be general reference.  However, it is also on Wikipedia, which would make that _part_ of this question a general reference:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley_Judd#Television

Comment: @MarkTrapp - maybe you mean "every single *incredibly beautiful* guest star" which might narrow the scope a bit.

Comment: Seems like something that IMDB could answer easily

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She also appeared in '[Darmok](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Darmok_%28episode%29)'.

Comment: Odd, I don't remember her in that episode at all. It wasn't one of my favorites, anyway. Was her role much smaller than in The Game?

Comment: Only in a couple of scenes.

Comment: She plays a major part in the game. In darmok she is Geordie's assistant while he's trying to focus the transporter beam.

As for darmok not your favourite. It's the best episode of trek imo ;)

Answer (score 48):

Ashley Judd played the character of [Robin Lefler](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Robin_Lefler) in two episodes:

- [Darmok](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708696/)
- [The Game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708798/)

The character's role in *Darmok* is not significant (she is part of *La Forge*'s team working on the transporter), but plays a major role in *The Game*.

With respect to denying her appearance, my guess is that you are referring to an apparent mention by Judd on *Letterman* that she would reprise the role in *Star Trek Nemesis* (there are many [references](http://www.google.com/search?q=ashley+judd+nemesis+letterman) to this, but I can't find anything authoritative - it was 2002).  This did not turn out to be the case, and was later denied by Judd's spokesperson (I can't find any authoritative source for this, either).

She certainly doesn't **deny** being in Star Trek as this video shows;

*Wesley Crusher*'s part in *Nemesis* was [certainly](http://www.wilwheaton.net/mt/archives/001089.php) cut; it's possible that Judd was cut too, or that Lefler was in an early script but never filmed.  There doesn't appear to be any definitive evidence either way.

Comment: Wesley Crusher made it in on screen in theaters; in the DVD version his one line scene with Picard at the Wedding was featured as a deleted scene.

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: @Stick - Dunno. It's an odd one.